# replacing a sub-partition (unordered list; multiset)

Tags: list-manipulation, replacement, pattern-matching

I am working on a bijection for integer partitions and would appreciate help with two steps.

First, I want to replace each occurrence of (4, 2, 1, 1) with (3, 3, 2).  One complication is that the 4, 2, 1, and 1 need not be adjacent.  For example, the input

> {{4, 4, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1}, {4, 4, 2, 2, 2, 1}}

should lead to the output

> {{4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1}, {4, 4, 2, 2, 2, 1}}

since the first partition does include (4, 2, 1, 1), even with the extra 2, and the second does not.

Second, in a later step, I need a 2 and all ones, suppose there are $k$ of them, to be changed to the single number $k+2$, e.g., input

> {{5, 2, 1, 1}, {4, 3, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1}}

should lead to the output

> {{5, 4}, {5, 2, 2}, {4, 3, 1, 1}}.

Edit: I put the part 2 output in the standard reverse lexicographic order used for partitions, which unfortunately caused some confusion.  Partition by partition, the intent is

> {5, 2, 1, 1} $\mapsto$ {5, 4},
>
> {4, 3, 1, 1} $\mapsto$ {4, 3, 1, 1},
>
> {2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1} $\mapsto$ {5, 2, 2}.

Comment: You’ve also sorted the second example in some way, is this desired?

Comment: The ordering of the three partitions is not essential.  I just put them in reverse lexicographic order, like the output of `IntegerPartitions[n]`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is my solution to the first part of your question:

```
ReverseSort/@
  SubsetReplace[{4, 2, 1, 1} -> Sequence[3, 3, 2]]/@
    {{4, 4, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1}, {4, 4, 2, 2, 2, 1}}

(* Out: {{4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1}, {4, 4, 2, 2, 2, 1}} *)
```

For the second part, this is as close as I got so far:

```
ReverseSort/@
  SubsetReplace[{2, p: Repeated[1, Infinity]} :> Length[{p}] + 2]/@
    {{5, 2, 1, 1}, {4, 3, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1}}

(* Out: {{5, 4}, {4, 3, 1, 1}, {5, 2, 2}} *)
```

Comment: Thanks!  I need to update to 12.1 so that I can use SubsetReplace.

Answer (score 5):

**Update**

---

As pointed out by [CA Trevillian](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/63039/ca-trevillian), `b___` in the answer to Part 1 is superfluous, and the order after `a___` does not matter, which improves things quite a bit.

A more succinct solution is as follows:

```
Replace[lst1, {OrderlessPatternSequence[a___,1,1,2,4]}:> ReverseSort[{a,2,3,3}],{1}]
```

---

**Original Answer**

```
 Replace[lst1, {OrderlessPatternSequence[a___,4,2,1,1,b___]}:> ReverseSort[{a,3,3,2,b}],{1}]
```

> {{4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1}, {4, 4, 2, 2, 2, 1}}

If order is unimportant:

```
Replace[lst1,  {OrderlessPatternSequence[a___,4,2,1,1,b___]}:> {a,3,3,2,b},{1}]
```

> {{3, 3, 2, 1, 2, 4}, {4, 4, 2, 2, 2, 1}}

**Part 2** (if I understand correctly):

```
Replace[lst2, {OrderlessPatternSequence[a___,2,c:Repeated[1]]}:> ReverseSort[{a,c+2}],{1}]
```

> {{5, 4}, {4, 3, 1, 1}, {5, 2, 2}}

**In response to comment by OP**

```
Replace[lst3, {OrderlessPatternSequence[a___,2,c:Repeated[1]]}:> ReverseSort[{a,c+2}],{1}]
```

> {{5, 4}, {4, 3, 1, 1}, {5, 2, 2}, {5}}

**data**

```
lst1={{4, 4, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1}, {4, 4, 2, 2, 2, 1}};

lst2={{5, 2, 1, 1}, {4, 3, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1}};
lst3={{5, 2, 1, 1}, {4, 3, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1},{2,1,1,1}};
```

**Update** (*Mathematica* version)

Obtained with Wolfram Language 12.0.0 Engine for Microsoft Windows (64-bit)

[OrderlessPatternSequence](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/OrderlessPatternSequence.html?view=all) was introduced in 2015 (10.1)

[Replace](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Replace.html) was introduced in 1988 (1.0), *but was updated in 2014* (10.0)

Comment: For clarity, can you put which version this is useable with? By that I ask, what version does this begin to be useable?

Comment: @CATrevillian I have updated as you suggested, re-ran the code checking the output, and removed  a couple of 'typos'.  (I do not have access to v 12.1).  Thanks for the feedback

Comment: `OrderlessPatternSequence` is the hero of this story. Thanks for the updated version clarifications.

Comment: Part 2 doesn't do what I hoped in the case of a single 2 followed by 1s.  E.g., it takes (2,2,1) correctly to (3,2) but takes (2,1,1,1) to (4,1) instead of the intended (5).  (And sorry for the confusion caused by the way I reordered the Part 2 output.)

Comment: @Brian, you could minimize the confusion by editing your question to state more clearly your preference of reverse-lexicographic ordering.

Comment: @BrianHopkins Ooops ....  Should have been a___ (triple-blank) instead of a__ (double-blank). (I also make this error in original answer to part 1)

Comment: @J.M. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @user1066 you don't need to use an additional `b___` in your first example, and the order, before/after the pattern which will be replaced, does not matter. Very nice! I like that this is backward compatible.

Comment: @CATrevillian That is a very good point.  Thanks! (I'll update)

Answer (score 3):

First part in version 10.1:

```
rep[{a__} -> {b__}] :=
  {OrderlessPatternSequence[x___, a]} :> Reverse@Sort@{x, b}

{{4, 4, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1}, {4, 4, 2, 2, 2, 1}} /. rep[{4, 2, 1, 1} -> {3, 3, 2}]
```

> ```
> {{4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1}, {4, 4, 2, 2, 2, 1}}
> ```

I didn't quite follow your second example; I'll update if I see the pattern.

Comment: "I didn't quite follow your second example" - the OP just sorted the list reverse-lexicographically again afterwards, but `{5, 2, 1, 1}` maps to `{5, 2 + 2}`, and `{2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1}` maps to `{2, 2, 2 + 3}`. Hopefully that clarifies the pattern for you.

Comment: Mr.Wizard, for the second example, you should just be able to use `rep[{2, c : (1) ..} -> {2 + c}]` -- oddly, though, this does not work. I think that has something to do with scoping of the contexts of the arguments when one uses symbols in this way? I think I said that correctly...